# How to include Tawk chat js on site build with Turbolinks

Tags: turbolinks, tawk.to

Putting following js from https://www.tawk.to/ to my page, it work first time, but it stops after navigating few page.

I've put following js to before the `</body>` tag on each single page.

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('tawk');
    window.$_Tawk = undefined;
    var $_Tawk_API={},$_Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
    (function(){
        var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async=true;
        s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/55ee5ff40fd62512247407c8/default';
        s1.charset='UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
    })();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: If you have a common footer, please include it there so that you don't miss any page. It works fine for me

Comment: I think i have the same issue here, if there's anyone can help, please let me know! BTW: I already add these script in every page!